# Group and reuse dependencies in gradle multiproject build

Tags: gradle

I have multiproject build in gradle. In `build.gradle` I have some dependencies the same for two or more projects:

```
project(":pr-common") {
  dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.3"
    compile "org.joda:joda-convert:1.6"
  }
}

project(":pr-domain") {
  dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.3"
    compile "org.joda:joda-convert:1.6"
  }
}
```

Can I somehow group and reuse this dependencies? I want something like this:

```
def joda = [
  compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.3", 
  compile "org.joda:joda-convert:1.6"
]

project(":pr-common") {
  dependencies {
    joda
  }
}

project(":pr-domain") {
  dependencies {
    joda
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reuse dependencies in the way You suggested. Instead, You can use the following piece of code.

**build.gradle** (root project)

```
subprojects.findAll { it.path.contains('pr') }.each { //whatever search condition
   it.plugins.apply 'groovy'

   it.dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'
      compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
   }
}
```